# Angular: How to do *ngFor in HTML

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have this HTML code in an Angular application and I want to display `ID_EXPEDIENTE` when you select it. However, when I click on it, nothing happens.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionIDExpedientes" >
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let ACPGPAE of ACPGPA.AuditedClientPeriodFileFieldGroupsAcreditadoExpedientes">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link btn-acreditados" data-toggle="collapse" attr.data-target="#{{ACPGPAE.ID_EXPEDIENTE}}" aria-expanded="true" attr.aria-controls="{{ACPGPAE.ID_EXPEDIENTE}}">
                    EXPEDIENTE: {{ACPGPAE.ID_EXPEDIENTE}}
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>    
        <div attr.id="{{ACPGPAE.ID_EXPEDIENTE}}" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordionIDExpedientes">
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ACPGPAE.DIAS_IMPAGO}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                   
</div>
```

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Inspect generated code. I am not sure whether it is an problem with Angular or Bootstrap.

Comment: may I ask what is `ACPGPA.AuditedClientPeriodFileFieldGroupsAcreditadoExpedientes`? Is it an object?

Comment: Hi,

i fixed it with a string in front of the variable.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong that when the user clicks on the button it will display the array of ID? or only display single ID per click?

Comment: Only will display a single ID.